# Remove extra appended characters to a text stored in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an api controller that collects information from the api users. However, some user information when sent and stored in the MySQL database sometimes its appears with added underscores like this `"this is a test ________"` instead of `this is a test`. However when run through the browser it stores just fine.

What could be the problem.

Controller extract;

```
@message.message = CGI.unescape(params[:message]).strip
```

As a temporary fix, any ideas how i can strip away all the 6 underscores that are being added to the message either in storage or when it comes.

```
class Api::V1::Json::MessagesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'
def sms
    @message = Message.new
    #@message.to = decoded_to.gsub(/[^\d]/,"")
    @message.to = CGI.unescape(params[:to]).strip.gsub("+","").gsub(/\s+/, "")
    @message.from =  CGI.unescape(params[:from])
    @message.message = CGI.unescape(params[:message]).strip
    @message.user_id = current_user.id
    @message.status = 'Queued'
    if @message.save
        MessageWorker.perform_async(@message.id, [""], current_user.id)
        render json: {status: "Success"} 
    else
        render json: {status: "Failed" }
    end
end

private

def authenticate
  error!('Unauthorized. Invalid token.', 401) unless current_user
end

def current_user
  # find token. Check if valid.
  user_token = params[:token]
  token = ApiKey.where(:access_token => user_token).first
  if token 
    @current_user = User.find(token.user_id)
  else
    false
  end
end
end
```

and the model is;

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :message, :phone, :status, :to, :from, :user_id
 attr_accessor :schedule
 validates :message, :presence => true
 validates :from, :presence => true
 validates :to, :presence => true
 validates :status, :presence => true
 validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 1600, :allow_blank => true
 validates_length_of :from, :maximum => 11, :allow_blank => false
 belongs_to :user
```

Comment: an idea: use `before_save` hook to strip those underscores.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, please illustrate

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Is that 6 underscores are consistent or differs ?

Comment: @shiva, its consistent to the api calls from a particular client.

Comment: post the request log from log/production.log

Comment: @shiva, weirdly my rails does not write to logs.

Comment: add `raise "Debug #{params.inspect}"` to your `sms` method and post the result

Answer (score 1):

Change your Model like this

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :strip_underscore

  def strip_underscore
   self.message.gsub("______","")
  end

end
```

Comment: Or if the number of `_`'s can vary use `.gsub(/_+$/,'')`

Comment: @shiva But above everything, why does it happen?

Comment: Need more details to inspect!

Comment: @shiva, i am going to add the entire API controller and the model